# Quartz.net JOB never wake up again even though schedule says it should run daily

Tags: quartz.net

I have schedule 13 JOBS all JOB working fine only 1 JOB have an issue with
wake up from sleep, It is working till some days and suddenly it is stop to rerun i haven't get any exception log,even next run scheduled properly and completed to run Quartz.IJobListener.JobWasExecuted and going on sleep and then never wake up untill i restart the service.

I have created Windows service for that and Create Parallel threads again each job using Parallel programming and running 2.5 version of Quartz.net

Today i have found Quartz give error as
Unhandle exception in SQLMonitorAlertProcess.JobToBeExecuted Quartz.SchedulerException: Trigger does not reference given job!
at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.ScheduleJob(IJobDetail jobDetail, ITrigger trigger)
at Quartz.Impl.StdScheduler.ScheduleJob(IJobDetail jobDetail, ITrigger trigger)
at .SQLMonitorAlertProcess.MyJobListener.Quartz.IJobListener.JobToBeExecuted (IJobExecutionContext
context)

One more thing is that my all 12 job have physical database connection and 1 job which have issue have azure connection string

could you please help me

Thanks

Comment: urmmm, if you dont know what is going on, and you have all the code in front of you (and you wrote it), how would you expect us to know whats going on, with no code?

Comment: @TheGeneral i have write lots of code so  its not possible to pest over here and code is same for all jobs then why issue with one job please help me if you face this type of issue thanks for comment

Comment: Yeah, this is called a [logic error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_error), the way we solve these are by reducing the amount of variables (degrees of freedom) until you can reproduce something, that either works, or doesn't work (in its minimalist form). its nearly impossible to solve this for you. Even if we had similar problems there are 1000s of variables that might make it different

Comment: There is no way to help you with the current question. The error is in your code. Or even if it isn't, it's *triggered* by your code. We don't know your code. That means we cannot help you.